# bootstrap accordian example in jsfiddle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jsfiddle

I'm trying to recreate the [bootstrap accordion example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion).

Why isn't this JSFiddle working?

https://jsfiddle.net/43Tesseracts/dqzdL73p/5/

The HTML is copy/pasted from the example, and bootstrap.min.js and css are provided.

The example says it uses `transition.js` but this is included in the compiled min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is the reason why it is not working in jsfiddle

The same code is working in other places.. Below is the example

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
>   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
>   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
>   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
>   <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
> </head>
> <body>
>
> <div class="container">
>   <h2>Collapsible List Group</h2>
>   <div class="panel-group">
>     <div class="panel panel-default">
>       <div class="panel-heading">
>         <h4 class="panel-title">
>           <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible list group</a>
>         </h4>
>       </div>
>       <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
>         <ul class="list-group">
>           <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
>           <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
>           <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
>         </ul>
>         <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
>       </div>
> <div class="panel-heading">
>         <h4 class="panel-title">
>           <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">Collapsible list group</a>
>         </h4>
>       </div>
> <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
>         <ul class="list-group">
>           <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
>           <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
>           <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
>         </ul>
>         <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
>
> </div>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: I would say use HTTPS URIs

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>